# JSON Schema v7: formatMinimum & formatMaximum validate everything

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I am using ajv json schema library (v7) and trying to validate a date based on some value. It looks pretty straightforward with using formatMinimum/formatMaximum but it seems that every date is validated when using these keywords

Here's my schema

```
   "some-date": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
               "value": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "format": "date-time",
                  "formatMinimum": "2021-03-10T14:25:00.000Z"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Here's the json:

```
{
   "some-date": {
      "data": {
         "value": "2011-03-10T14:25:00.000Z"
      }
   }
}
```

Here's how I am validating:

```
const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true})

require('ajv-formats')(ajv)
require('ajv-errors')(ajv)
require('ajv-keywords')(ajv)

const validate = ajv.validate(mySchema)
const isValid = validate(myJSON)
```

I've tried it on JSONSchemalint and it validates the above json with the given schema. Also, I have tried with several dates and it validates everything.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting formatMinimum and formatMaximum from, but they are not standard keywords in the JSON Schema specification, under any version. Are they documented as supported keywords in the implementation that you are using?

Comment: You can use them with the 'ajv-keywords' package. See here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv/v/6.12.5#formats

Comment: In that case you should file an issue directly with the ajv project.